# Discord Bot that auto disconnect deafen users

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm looking for discord bot that can auto disconnect users when they press on deafen button

if there none can it even be done ?

and if it can be achieved What Will It Take ( i didn't create discord bot before )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Client#voiceStateUpdate` event, which will trigger when a user is deafened, among other things. You can then check if the event was triggered specifically from someone deafening by checking if [`VoiceState#selfDeaf`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=selfDeaf) is true. If it is, you can use [`VoiceState#kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=kick) to kick them. It is recommended you first check [`VoiceState#member#manageable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=manageable) first to make sure you can kick them.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (newState.deafened && newState.member.manageable) {
    newState.kick();
  }
});
```

Comment: it didn't work till i removed `&& newState.member.manageable`
any idea why ? @Lioness100

Comment: I think it's because you have a higher role than your bot. I originally put in that line because I thought you couldn't disconnect people that were higher in the hierarchy than you, but upon further inspection it seems if you have the permission you can disconnect anyone.

Comment: i updated the code to send msg to the disconnected user 
`newState.kick().then(()=>{ newState.member.send("You got disconnected for being muted"); });`
it works fine but the bot send it twice am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i found a good fix `if (newState.selfDeaf && newState.member.voice.channel)`
to prevent the code from being execute twice which by checking if user is connected to voice channel